# how do I get round CORS in angular 9

Tags: angular, cors

I receive the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:40000/api/summaryCount/failed-requests' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have created a proxy.conf.json file with the following:

```
{"/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:40000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I have also amended my angular.json file to include

```
"proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
```

on the "serve": { "options" { ......

and finally I have amended my package.json  so that the "start" option now becomes:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

in my Angular when creating the HttpHeaders object, if I add the following:

```
httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000').....
```

it still makes no difference.

can someone tell me what I've missed please.

Comment: Have you set header such as 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' ?

Comment: what backend are you using? `.NET` or `NodeJS`?

Comment: I'm using .NET as my backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable `CORS` and whitelist your Angular app URL `http://localhost:3000` on your backend server which serves at `http://localhost:40000/api/...`.

No action required on Angular app side.

Comment: my backend Server written in C# has `var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorsAllowedOrigins"], "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
            config.EnableCors(cors);`

Answer (score 0):

In backend server, you have to write **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** as * and if you prevent from a specific URL then you can also write the URL there.